# uint8 dtypes to numerical in a conditional dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a df where all of it values are numerical (integers, floats..). However, the dtype of some columns is "uint8" and I'm trying to change all the columns with dtype "uint8" to int64. However, I can't even check the dtype of the df:

```
for i in df.columns:
    train_analisis_num[i].dtype == uint8
```

It gives me the error that `uint8` is not defined. I have tried with `"uint8"` too, but also doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What makes you think uint8 is not a numeric dtype? uint8 is unsigned 8-bit integers.

Comment: ups !. Mistake corrected!. It just python doesn't work with it as a numerical, it receives it as an error. So I'm trying to change to an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string name for the 8-byte unsigned integer dtype is `'u1'`.

Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html